# BulkInsert CSV into DB - Why is my last row being inserted twice

Tags: sql-server, bulkinsert

I'm attempting to import a csv into my database using a bulk insert.

My code looks like this:

```
CREATE PROCEDURE AddCSVQuestions
    @CSV_File_Loc varchar(255)
AS
    DECLARE @sql varchar(max)

    SET @sql = 'BULK INSERT Database.Table FROM ''' + @CSV_FILE_LOC +  
''' WITH (FIRE_TRIGGERS, FIRSTROW=2, FIELDTERMINATOR='','', ROWTERMINATOR=''\n'' )'

    EXEC(@sql)

    RETURN
GO
```

---------EDIT---------

As per request this is the csv template.

```
Language, JobSkill, QuestionID, DateAdded, Author, Question, Answer, Hint
ENG, C++, 10,,TestAuthor, TestQuestion, TestAnswer, TestHint
ENG, SQL, 11,,TestAuthor, TestQuestion, TestAnswer, TestHint
```

Note: There is no date because there is a trigger that will set the date to be today's date.

------END EDIT-------

When this procedure is called with a csv with 3 rows, the header row is skipped, then the second row isn't saved but the third is saved twice.

What could be causing this?

Comment: Please post your file.

Comment: There could be an issue of row terminator. Please try '0x0a' instead of '\n'.

Comment: I added the CSV template that I'm using. I hope this was the file you are asking for.

Comment: @sacse The issue persists. Thanks for the suggestion tho.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I tried to load the test file and it loaded successfully:

[image]

File data:

[image]

Comment: @NotAFrontEndDev might be you were not checking in the correct table.

Comment: No, I'm sure I'm looking in the correct table. Two new SQL rows values are showing up in the table every time I execute. Thank you for testing it out. I'll try to recreate my database and see if that resolves the issue.

Comment: @NotAFrontEndDev ok, good luck. thanks for accepting the answer.